# Binary Search Tree Multiply nodes by -1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Consider you have `Binary Search Tree`, in case  `multiply all nodes by -1` then can anybody please let me know if its still a `Binary Search Tree`?

Whether is it possible to write a function which converts it back to `Binary Search Tree` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.

In a `Binary Search Tree`, the structure of object graph indicates the sort ordering.

By multiplying all of the object by -1, it's now *reverse* sorted.

EG:

```
3 4 8 9 12
```

becomes

```
-3 -4 -8 -9 -12
```

---

So, how do you make this still maintain the Binary Search Tree property?

A binary tree would consist of two things: a graph of object nodes, and the knowledge on how to compare the objects. The comparison function would look something like this:

```
 Compare(left, right) {
     return (left < right);
 }
```

If you perform a transformation on the values inside your binary tree, you can change its comparison function and then it will continue to behave as it should.

```
 myBinaryTree.comparisonFunction = function(left, right) { return (right < left) };
```

Answer (score 1):

In a binary search tree, all elements of a node's left subtree must be less than (or equal to, in some trees) the node and all elements of a node's right subtree must be greater than (or equal to, in some trees) the node. If you multiply all the nodes by -1, you end up flipping this so that the left subtree of each node stores the greater values and the right subtree stores the lesser values. To convert this back into a BST, you'd have to "flip" the BST by mirroring it. I'll leave the details of how to do that as an exercise; it's a classic CS problem with a beautiful recursive solution.

Hope this helps!